# Dificuldades ao pegar valores dentro de array

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou fazendo um código onde seleciono informações do banco e alimento uma array, na sequência estou tentando utilizar o conteúdo dessa array para comparar com outras informações e processar o restante do código.

Porém estou tendo dificuldades pra pegar os dados de dentro da array, abaixo meu código:

```
<?php
    $fuso    = mktime(date("H")-3, date("i"), 0);
    $hoje    = gmdate("Y-m-d", $fuso);
    //$resultado_array = array(); //sem o array
    $agendamentos = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE data_agendamento='$hoje'");
    while($row = $agendamentos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if ($row['hora_agendamento'] == "08:00:00") { //agora com $row
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['hora_agendamento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_paciente'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['observacao'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_agendamento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>Editar</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>08:00:00</td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td>Editar</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        if ($row['hora_agendamento'] == "09:00:00") { //agora com $row
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['hora_agendamento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_paciente'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['observacao'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id_agendamento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>Editar</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>09:00:00</td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td></td>';
            echo '<td>Editar</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }

    } //while agora só termina aqui

    echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

No if caso encontre dentro da array a string ali determinada ele deveria preencher os dados abaixo, mas logo ao começar o if já apresenta o erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: hora_agendamento in
>   C:\wamp64\www\agendamentos\index.php on line 29

Claramente porque não estou conseguindo pegar os dados dentro da array, como proceder?

Comment: Mas a ideia era construir uma tabela com todos os agendamentos que tem hora `08:00` ? Ou apenas o primeiro ?

Comment: Todos, mas vai ter só 1 agendamento, não vou permitir mais de 1 agendamento no mesmo horário no mesmo dia. Nesse código ele tá sendo só um parâmetro pra quando encontrar na array esse horário, ele preencher a tabela com o restante dos dados daquela linha da array.

Comment: ja tentou usar o var_dump para verificar como ficou a estrutura do seu array??

Tente executar assim logo depois do while: 
`var_dump($resultado_array);`  e veja o q retorna, se mesmo assim não encontrar o caminho para pegar o seu array, edita sua pergunta com o resultado do var_dump.

Comment: `hora_agendamento` não é um valor index da array. Valor index de uma array é um número (0, 1, 2, 3...).

Answer (score 1):

O que está a tentar fazer não faz muito sentido. Está a guardar as linhas todas que vem da tabela num array:

```
while($row = $agendamentos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($resultado_array,$row); //<- aqui com array_push
```

Mas depois utiliza como se fosse apenas um objeto normal e não um array:

```
if ($resultado_array['hora_agendamento'] == "08:00:00.00000") {
```

Para utilizar como um array tem de especificar a posição, por exemplo:

```
if ($resultado_array[0]['hora_agendamento'] == "08:00:00.00000") {
```

Repare que indiquei posição 0 com `[0]`.

Mas isto cria-lhe outro problema pois ou apenas usa o primeiro (e pode até nem existir!) ou tem de utilizar novamente outro `while` para utilizar as várias linhas. Melhor é mesmo utilizar o `while` que já tinha inicialmente e aplicar a lógica e escrita lá:

```
<!--O inicio da tabela é html normal por isso pode ficar escrito como html-->
<table id="tableteste" class="table table-striped" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hora</th>
            <th>Paciente</th>
            <th>Observação</th>
            <th>Agendamento</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    $fuso    = mktime(date("H")-3, date("i"), 0);
    $hoje    = gmdate("Y-m-d", $fuso);
    //$resultado_array = array(); //sem o array
    $agendamentos = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM agendamentos WHERE data_agendamento='$hoje'");

    while($row = $agendamentos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        if ($row['hora_agendamento'] == "08:00:00.00000") { //agora com $row
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $resultado_array['hora_agendamento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $resultado_array['id_paciente'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $resultado_array['observacao'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $resultado_array['id_agendamento'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>Editar</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    } //while agora só termina aqui

    echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Meu código era exatamente assim(editei o post principal lá), porém como tu pode ver, quando existe if e else, quando o resultado se encaixa no else o código repete várias vezes o resultado, veja só quando não há registros para a hora 09:00:00: https://imgur.com/a/WMRaD

Comment: @FernandoGross Não pode estar dessa forma. Tem que ser o primeiro `if` para `"08:00:00"` depois `else if` para `"09:00:00"` e depois então o `else` normal. Essa seria a forma de fazer se quiser ter 2 casos e um terceiro para tudo o resto. Mas no seu código nem sequer consegui perceber a diferença entre os vários casos, pois parecem me iguais à exceção da hora. E a hora já é mostrada na tabela, logo o `if` nem parece ter sentido.

Comment: Meu deus, sou retardado haha... A ideia desses else if é preencher a tabela com os horários que tem dados no banco e os que não tem gerarem linhas em branco, depois ao clicar editar eu vou abrir um modal ou algo do tipo pra inserir um agendamento novo naquele espaço desocupado, por agora ele não faz muito sentido mesmo, e foi o jeito mais prático que eu achei pra fazer uma agenda que encaixasse no meu plano, pode haver outro jeito, mas usando o que eu sei aparentemente é isso aí.